# Using Internal APIs Rest client

Tags: java, apache, rest

I am using a REST client code which currently uses the below imports which are declared as internal APIs and as per our testing tool should be avoided. What is the possible alternatives.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;

This class makes use of internal API classes. As these classes are not documented, nor externally released as part of the API, they are subject to change or removal. You should not be using these classes.

Packages that shouldn't be used are: 

    •sun.xxx
    •org.apache.xerces.xxx
    •org.apache.xalan.xxx
```

Comment: Apache http package seems to be populate and is used in many projects. Maybe convince your QA to change their rule for Apache?

Comment: Hello @TungstenX, thanks for the response but that's not possible unfortunately. Are their some alternatives which can be used?

Comment: Have you consider googling `apache http alternative`?

Comment: Tried that but no correct results.